# Probability: expectancy of offsprings after 23 years

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

**Hi all, thanks for reading & helping.
An alien lives for 5 years, gives birth to a certain number of offsprings Z~Poisson(lambda) and then dies.
Given there are 2 aliens now: 1 year old, and 3 years old, what is the expextancy of aliens we assume to have in 23 years?**

Basically I looked at it like a Geometric progression problem, but I know i should approach it somehow from the angle of the Law of total expectation.
I thought about creating a variant Y- number of expected in the i-th generation, and X_i which represents the number of offsprings we assume which alien in the i-th generation would yield, but Im not sure how to operate it.
any help?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_n$ and $B_n$ be the number of aliens living in year $n$ (for $n\geqslant0$) descended from the $1$-year old and $3$-year old aliens, respectively. These are Galton-Watson branching processes, and it can be shown that the expected number of offspring after generation $k$ is $\lambda^k$ (where $\lambda$ is the mean of the offspring distribution). By year 23, there will be four generations descended from the $1$-year old alien and five from the $3$-year old alien. It follows then that
$$ 
\mathbb E[A_{23} + B_{23}] = \lambda^4 + \lambda^5.
$$

Comment: thanks for your informative answer!
does that include those from the 1st to 3rd generations that passes?